# JavaScript Recorder

Tags: javascript, dom-events, recorder

I'm fairly new to Javascript and would love to understand what this piece of code can do. Its a recorder for a web game. I wanted to know if it triggers itself when the window pops or there is another trigger and what it does.

```
(function (window) {
    const __DEBUG__ = (location.hostname === "localhost" || location.hostname === "127.0.0.1");

    if (!__DEBUG__) {
        if (!window.console) window.console = {};
        var methods = ["log", "debug", "warn", "info"];
        for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            console[methods[i]] = function () {
            };
        }
    }

    // We declare some stuff here
    const _data = {
        recorderFunc: null,
        eventsRR: [],
        events: [],
        elements: {
            replayerId: 'target'
        }
    };

    window.Recorder = Recorder = {};

    Recorder.cc = function () {
        console.log('Começou a conversão...');
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var convert_canvas = new Image();

        setInterval(function () {
            convert_canvas.width = $('#canvas').width();
            convert_canvas.height = $('#canvas').height();
            convert_canvas.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.1);

            $('#convert_canvas').css('top', $('#canvas').css('top'));
            $('#convert_canvas').css('left', $('#canvas').css('left'));
            $('#convert_canvas').empty().append(convert_canvas);

        }, 1000);
    }

    Recorder.r = function () {
        console.log('Começou a gravar...');
        _data.recorderFunc = rrweb.record({
            emit(event) {
                _data.events.push(event);
                console.log(event);
            },
            packFn: rrweb.pack,
            sampling: {
                mouseInteraction: {
                    MouseUp: false,
                    MouseDown: false,
                    Click: false,
                    ContextMenu: false,
                    DblClick: false,
                    Focus: false,
                    Blur: false,
                    TouchStart: false,
                    TouchEnd: false,
                },
                mousemove: true,
                scroll: 300, // do not emit twice in 150ms
                input: 'last'
            },
            inlineStylesheet: false,
            blockSelector: 'canvas',
            blockClass: 'rr-block',
            ignoreClass: 'rr-ignore'
        });
    };

    $(window).on("blur focus", function (e) {
        var prevType = $(this).data("prevType");

        if (!window.record_canvas)
            return;

        if (prevType != e.type) {   //  reduce double fire issues
            switch (e.type) {
                case "blur":
                    Recorder.s()
                    break;
                case "focus":
                    Recorder.r();
                    break;
            }
        }

        $(this).data("prevType", e.type);
    })

    Recorder.s = function () {
        console.log('A gravaçao pausou...');
        _data.recorderFunc();
    };

    Recorder.se = function (level, uuid, _key, _iv) {
        //document.getElementById("processing").style.display = "block";
        // Check if the received level has already been recorded.
        // If so, ignore the rest of the function.
        //if (window.recordedLevels.indexOf(level) !== -1) {
        //    return;
        //}

        // Otherwise, let's send it to the server and add it to
        // the list of recorded levels (so it won't be recorded again).
        //window.recordedLevels.push(level);

        console.info('Sending recorded events...', _data.events);

        if (!_data.events.length) {
            console.info('Skipping as there are no events to send...');
            return;
        }

        const eventsToBeSent = _data.events;
        _data.events = [];

        console.info('---- Clearing recorded events...', eventsToBeSent);

        // setTimeout(function () {
        var evt = LZString.compressToEncodedURIComponent(JSON.stringify(eventsToBeSent));

        $.ajax({
            url: 'actions.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            data: {
                data: encrypt(_key, _iv, JSON.stringify({
                    action: 'event',
                    re: evt,
                    l: level,
                    user_account_uuid: uuid,
                }))
            }
        }); /*.done(function (data) {
            //setTimeout(function () {
            //    document.getElementById("processing").style.display = "none";
            //}, 100);

            _data.events = [];
        });*/
        //}, 100);
    }

    function encrypt(_key, _iv, message) {
        let key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(_key);
        let iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(_iv);
        return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, {iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding}).toString();
    }

})(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in that piece of code, the Recorder seems to be defined when the window is opened, but I don't see anything triggering it for the first time. The only triggers I can see here are the "focus" and "blur" handlers, but they will only be called when the user interacts with the browser tab/window.

That said, this code seems to start recording the game area as soon as the user adds `focus` on the game tab, and stop recording it when the user leaves (`blur`). To record the content, this lib is being used: https://www.rrweb.io/.

That's what we can be sure of in this code, even though there are more functions which purposes are not clear, like `Recorder.cc`. It converts the game area into an image, but it's hard to say exactly why and when it's used.

My guess is that piece of code is used as a reporting tool to understand what event, or series of events, crashed the game, to speed up debugging.